# How can I find weight used for feature_count_ in scikit-learn classifiers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am looking at the fields contained in a MultinomialNB classifier and I am trying to derive the feature_count_ by hand doing the frequency count but it doesn't match with the results I see. In the documentation is said that

> This value is weighted by the sample weight when provided.

Where is this weight or how can I calculate it?

Here's the full example:

```
X_train, X_test = ['vecindario', 'friends'], ['amigos', 'neighbourhood']
Y_train, Y_test = [0, 1], [0, 1]

# Use vect = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(3, 3), analyzer='char', use_idf=False)
# clf = MultinomialNB()
# clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
vect.vocabulary_
>>> {'ari' : 0 , 'cin' : 1 , 'dar' : 2 , 'eci' : 3 , 'end' : 4 , 'fri' : 5 , 'ien' : 6 , 'ind' : 7 , 'nda' : 8 , 'nds' : 9 , 'rie' : 10, 'rio' : 11, 'vec' : 12}
clf.feature_count_
>>> [   
     [ 0.35355339  0.35355339  0.35355339  0.35355339  0.          0.          0.         0.35355339  0.35355339  0.          0.          0.35355339  0.35355339]
     [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.4472136   0.4472136   0.4472136  0.          0.          0.4472136   0.4472136   0.          0.        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature count works as expected and I don't think uses any weights by default. Might need more information to solve this one.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
X = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,3,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X, y)
print clf.feature_count_
```

Result:

```
[[ 2.  3.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  2.]]
```

Note that that the feature count does take the *sum* of your features. The two rows that correspond to class 1 in `X` are the first and fourth row. If you add them up, you get the first row in result.

Comment: I added a full example